# User Account Control warning showed everytime I run an installed program

Tags: windows-8, uac

I just installed Windows 8 on my computer. Next I installed a program for prototyping (Pencil). Everytime I run this program I have the following Warning:

---

**User Account Control**

Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer?

---

I prefer not disable the User Account Control.

Is there a way to stop User Account to warn me for this program?

Thanks.

Comment: Its an unsigned app, you cannot change this behavior other than disable UAC, which seems stupid, but hey its Microsoft...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/54c7e4da-e6c3-4771-8c3a-d7c09bccc8e9

Comment: I did find this, not sure if it works in W8...http://efreedom.com/Question/3-115107/Turn-Unknown-Publisher-Message-Older-Windows-Application

Comment: Let me know if the second link advice works in W8 if you decide to try it.

Comment: @Moab Page not found

Answer (score 1):

In normal circumstances, the only way to disable the prompt is to disable UAC. Even if the application is signed with a valid digital signature, still UAC will prompt for your consent(but with a subdued UAC prompt.)

In case you are Ok with the subdued UAC prompt and you are a developer at heart, you can go ahead and sign that application with a test digital certificate. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325833/Basics-of-Signing-and-Verifying-code) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That is not a warning, it's a request for your consent to allow the program to run with
elevated privileges. If you have not inadvertently asked Windows to start the program elevated (by editing its shortcut, for instance), then the program itself is asking for elevation, and presumably will malfunction if it's not granted. There is little point in having UAC turned on if any program can run as administrator without first obtaining the approval of an actual administrator. An unsigned program can easily be spoofed by another malicious program.